# Google Play games Unity plugin error: "Invalid classname"

Tags: unity-game-engine, plugins, google-play-games

I'm getting an error when I try to setup the Google Play Games in Unity.

Google Play Games plugin version: 0.10.12

I have two versions of a single game project. One is with Unity version 2019.4.15f1. Other is with 2021.3.2f1.

The new version has some changes and fixes to the game and different ads provider, so I can't just use the older version just for the Google Play Games plugin.

When I use this plugin with Unity version 2019, I am able to save the configuration, but when I use the same plugin with Unity version 2021, I keep getting this error:

```
Invalid classname: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

[image]

I tried downgrading to 0.9.53 but that causes the same issue in 2021, and I also tried upgrading to 0.11.01 which seems to save the configuration, but doesn't have the option to sign out of google play games which is necessary for me.

Comment: What class name did you pick?

Comment: @BugFinder I didn't change the default class name. The name is "GPGSIds"

Answer (score 0):

I also got that error but now I solved it.
Using Unity version "2020.3.23f1.
It will be okay.
If you do, the error comes out then reboot your computer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).